# to show total record in wanted date row

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieved data from my table by summing result and show in table.I want to show sum result record between date='2014-01' and date='2014-04' in 2014-04 column name.And then,I want to retrieve other sum result in 2014-05 to current date.
How can I do that?

```
SELECT MONTH(regist_timestamp) AS Month, YEAR(regist_timestamp) AS Year,
count(id) AS numberOfVisits FROM ash_members WHERE 
DATE(regist_timestamp) < CURDATE() GROUP BY 
DATE_FORMAT(`regist_timestamp`,'%Y/%m' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Format the date on `SELECT` then `GROUP BY`. Try with -

```
SELECT MONTH(regist_timestamp) AS Month, YEAR(regist_timestamp) AS Year, 
count(id) AS numberOfVisits, DATE_FORMAT(`regist_timestamp`,'%Y/%m' ) formatted_date
FROM ash_members
WHERE DATE(regist_timestamp) < CURDATE()
GROUP BY formatted_date
```